# AWS RDS with auto scaling feature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, high-availability

is there any way to auto scale AWS RDS?. I know about read replicas. What we are experiencing is that our peaks on RDS are relatively very small. Is there any possibility that we can scale short term on peak and then rollback after it?

(What I was thinking is to use AWS cloudwatch to get RDS metric and if it is > 90% then launch an EC2 instance in auto scaling group with database application install in it and connect it with a our architecture and destroy it when peak goes down) is it possible? TIA

Comment: do you want to use aws rds only? or is there a flexibility to choose some another aws database?

Comment: Which RDS database engine are you using? If you are using PostgreSQL or MySQL you can switch to using AWS Aurora which does have autoscaling of read replicas.

Comment: We are using RDS on mysql. is it possible that I use EC2 instances as read replicas with autoscaling group?

Answer (score 2):

What db engines are you using? If thats MySQL or PgSQL you can use Aurora read replica auto scaling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html

This is a managed service by AWS to auto scale out read replica when read traffic is high and scale in when traffic is low.

But notice that the write instance still cannot auto scale, this is basically a general limitation for relational db in general--> the write instance can only scale vertically with downtime.

However Aurora Serverless v2 : https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/, which is in preview is going to solve the issue as you can scale in/out both write and read capacity within seconds.

Comment: Assuming that aurora db is aws proprietary stuff which would make moving to other cloud providers difficult, any cloud agnostic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called vertical scaling and it's possible with minimal downtime in Multi-AZ RDS. This is different than horizontal scaling with read replicas, your master instance is replaced by a scaled copy in the other AZ. You can find a short write up with the [console steps here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/). It should be fairly straightforward to create a cloudwatch event that does this automatically.

Comment: While it's unlikely that AWS documentation links will break, on the off chance they do, this answer will no longer be useful. Please consider updating your answer to include the relevant information directly.